# MaTeX produces strange error

Tags: plotting, latex, matex

I've managed to install and configure matex, however when I try to run it the following error arise:

```
<< MaTeX`

StartProcess::nffil: File not found during RunProcess. >>

StringMatchQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[StringTrim[$Failed[StandardOutput]],DigitCharacter..~~.~~DigitCharacter..]. >>

StringSplit::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringSplit[StringTrim[$Failed[StandardOutput]],.]. >>

FromDigits::nlst: The expression StringTrim[$Failed[StandardOutput]] is not a list of digits or a string of valid digits. >>

FromDigits::nlst: The expression . is not a list of digits or a string of valid digits. >>

StringSplit::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringSplit[FromDigits[StringTrim[$Failed[StandardOutput]]],FromDigits[.]]. >>
```

If you could help me out with this i'd appreciate this

Comment: This is not a typical error, and is going to require discussion to resolve. StackExchange is not appropriate for that. I suggest we talk in the MaTeX chatroom: https://gitter.im/MaTeX-help/Lobby

Comment: Be sure to check [the troubleshooting section of the MaTeX webpage](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) in good time, but you are welcome to join the chatroom *right now* if you have time.

Comment: I'll be able to join the chat in the evening, maybe you will be there too.

Comment: Sorry, I won't be around later tonight (European time), but I can respond tomorrow. Some very important points are missing from your question: MaTeX version (always use the latest!), Mathematica version, your operating system, your precise configuration.  I suggest you go through [the troubleshooting](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), download the troubleshooting notebook (as described there), evaluate it, and email it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution to the problem, but it is good to note that we established in private e-mail that the underlying problem is that `RunProcess` simply does not work on the OP's machine (Mathematica 10.1.0 on Windows).

For example,

```
RunProcess["C:\\Windows\\System32\\where.exe"]
```

results in

> StartProcess::nffil: File not found during RunProcess.

even though

```
FileExistsQ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\where.exe"]
```

gives `True` and `where.exe` is present on all Windows systems.

Comment: Looks like a permission problem...

Comment: @yarchik We made some progress on this and it looks like RunProcess will fail if there are non-ASCII characters in the pathname of the working directory. I'm pretty sure it's a Mathematica bug