# RunProcess not working on Windows (looking for information on this problem)

Tags: windows, external-calls

I am the author of [the MaTeX package](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX), and occasionally I receive support requests from users in e-mail.  By now I believe I have ironed out virtually all bugs in MaTeX, and worked around most Mathematica bugs that cause issues in MaTeX, with one exception.

I received [several problem reports](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183119/12) where the root cause turned out to be that `RunProcess` simply does not work on the user's computer.

Common features I was able to identify are:

- This is Windows-specific
- It *may* affect only older versions of Mathematica, but this is unclear
- It *may* happen only when the default Windows character set is not ANSI / Windows-1252. This is typically the case when the language of Windows is not English or a Western European language. But this is again unclear.
- It may be related to non-ASCII characters in the username (and thus the home directory path), though this is unlikely.

The problem is reproducible like this:

Assuming that Windows is installed in `C:\Windows`, evaluate

```
RunProcess["C:\\Windows\\System32\\where.exe"]
```

This will return `$Failed` along with the following error message:

> StartProcess::nffil: File not found during RunProcess.

This is despite `where.exe` being present in that location. `FileExistsQ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\where.exe"]` will return `True`.

**I am looking for help** with:

- Establishing which systems are affected by the problem. Thus, if you use Mathematica on Windows, and your Windows is set to a non-English, non-Western-European language, please let me know if you can reproduce the problem, along with your Mathematica version.
- Finding a workaround for the problem. MaTeX relies on `RunProcess`, and reads the error code, the standard output and the standard error from the process. The workaround must allow `RunProcess` to work somehow (`Run` is not sufficient).

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Mathematica 10.0, Windows 10. @Szabolcs: have you found a way around?

Comment: @DenisCousineau I wasn't even able to reproduce the problem on my own machine, but I suspect that it has to do with non-English settings. If you have the possibility to upgrade to a newer Mathematica version, you should do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.