# MaTeX stopped accepting certain font sizes

Tags: fonts, matex

**My system:** Windows 10, Mathematica 11.2

**Problem:** I have been using the fine MaTeX paclet to get nice symbols on my plots. As I scale the images in a TeX-document after exporting them in EPS, I need to adjust the `FontSize`. So far things have worked out the way I wanted them to. But this week Mathematica has been acting up.

A command like

```
ec = ContourPlot[y^2 == x^3 - 5 x + 6, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5},
   Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {MaTeX["x"], MaTeX["y"]}]
```

works just fine, produces the expected image with nicely rendererd `AxesLabels`. But when I try

```
ec = ContourPlot[y^2 == x^3 - 5 x + 6, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5},
   Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {MaTeX["x", FontSize -> 18], 
    MaTeX["y", FontSize -> 18]}]
```

instead, I get a strange message with a tiny garbage image followed by a text like "MapThread[...". Having isolated the problem, the next thing to do was to try the input

```
MaTeX["x", FontSize -> 18]
```

This gave the following message that is all Greek to me, but hopefully somebody here can make sense out of it. I omitted most of the contents of the GraphicsBox for it's rather long. If judged essential, I will copy/paste all of it.

> MapThread[
>    Show[#1, ImageSize -> {#2, #3}, 
>      BaselinePosition -> 
>       Scaled[(#4 + MaTeX`Private`$psfactor)/#3]] &, {{\!\(\*
> GraphicsBox[
> AspectRatio->Automatic,
> ImageSize->{12., 24.},
> PlotRange->{{0., 11.97}, {0., 23.51}}]\)}, 
>   0.996264 (2 + 
>  Interpreter`DependentTypes`PackagePrivate`coerced$5234), \
>   {23.5118}, {6.45585}}]

**Search:** It is not impossible that my problem is related to that of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183119/1155). However, Szabolcs' diagnosis does not seem to fit here given that *MaTeX in the exact same notebook worked a week ago*. Therefore it is unlikely that for example Scandic letters in the path name would play a role. Furthermore, the path to this notebook is all ASCII-characters anyway.

---

Update:

**More testing:**

It seems to me that the choice of FontSize plays a role.

In a virgin session, the first call to MaTeX, asking for `FontSize->16` greeted me with the following:

> Fold::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 3 in Fold[Insert[#1,{},#2]&,MapThread[Replace[#1,Failure[Interpreter`Internal`PackagePrivate`args___,Interpreter`Internal`PackagePrivate`a:Blank[<<1>>]]:>Failure[Interpreter`Internal`PackagePrivate`args,Join[Interpreter`Internal`PackagePrivate`a,Association[<<2>>]]]]&,{<<1>>,{8.90271}}],Interpreter`DependentTypes`PackagePrivate`pos$3165].

Together with a lot of messages:

> Symbol::argx: Symbol called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.

Next, when I asked for an 18-point font, I got the plot together with typeset strings all right. But at the bottom of that cell there was something extra starting with `Show[#1, ImageSize->{#2,#3},...`

---

Next, when I asked for a 20-point font. **THERE WERE NO PROBLEMS.**

So has something destroyed my collection of fonts this last week?

---

A clue to the above test was that copy/pasting [the snippet from Szabolcs' page](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) worked as prescribed. So `Magnification -> 2` works fine.

Comment: FWIW I have been using MaTeX within the same installation of Mathematica since August. Mostly in the same selected folders.

Comment: Superficially, it looks like an issue with Mathematica itself (all that internal Interpreter stuff), not MaTeX, and not actually related to the font size. Do try a `ClearMaTeXCache[]`. I am going offline in a couple of hours and won't be around for about a week, so unfortunately I can't dig into this now.

Comment: P.S. 1. I can't reproduce the problem. 2. The Mathematica version may be relevant. 3. The "Symbol called with 0 arguments" reinforces my suspicion that this is a bug in Mathematica. It will likely temporarily go away with a kernel restart ...

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs. Yes my experiences from last Friday (when I temporarily had the same problem), and further testing now both indicate that this is an on/off  thing. Just a few minutes ago I got a few of the offending font sizes to work. I will report, if I find something reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also started happening to me sometime last week. I have no clue what triggered the change, since I have not updated anything manually.

Unfortunately, I don't have a proper fix, but a simple workaround I've found is to run the following snippet once at the beginning of the notebook,

```
Quiet[MaTeX["x"]];
ClearMaTeXCache[];
```

MaTeX can be used normally afterwards.

Comment: `ClearMaTeXCache[]` definitely helps. For a reason I cannot understand I need to give that command twice. Or, doing it at the beginning only will still produce that error message. But, giving it again, and then reinputting the `Plot`-command makes the problem disappear. I am accepting this for now as a fix, but I don't think the problem is completely understood yet. Of course, I don't know the inner workings of MaTeX.

Comment: Now I think I understand why the `Quiet` command is necessary. Without it the first MaTeX call generates an error message. `ClearMaTeXCache` has no effect without first having generated an error. Doing that error 'quietly' is much less disturbing :-)